# How do i get all the values from 2 tables without doing a Cross Join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables with the following Schema

`First ( id, user_id, user_agent, referrer, browser, device_type, IP)`

`Second ( id, user_id, name, properties)`

Table **First** has a total of 512 entries for **user_id** 1. Table **Second** has total of 100 entries for **user_id** 1. Both tables track different User Activities, so anytime I try to join Table ***Second*** on ***First*** for **user_id** 1.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM first f
JOIN second AS s ON s.user_id = f.user_id
WHERE f.user_id = 1
```

I get a total of 51,200 returned rows. Definitely, a Cross Join (first * second) is being done. Is there no way I can get a less enormous returned result? perhaps **first + second** resul

Comment: What is the reason to have 100 entries for user_id 1 in table `Second`? How are they different if they represent the same user? This seems to be the core reason to have 51 200 returned rows instead of 512.

Comment: 'perhaps first + second result' - sounds good consider UNION ALL

Comment: What exactly do you want the result to be? Create a mock example to demonstrate what you want. Other than executing two queries (one per table) I have no idea what you want this to actually do. Pleas read this stackoverflow page: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: @MatBailie I want a returned result with columns from both tables

`id, user_id, user_agent, referrer, browser, device_type, IP , user_id, name, properties`

Both tables have **user_id** in common

Comment: @samlexxy your last comment states a completely different requirement to the question.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm both tables track user actions. When an action is performed, data is added to either to either table, depending on the type of action. That's we have more than one entry for a particular user

Comment: Please create a mock example and read the post I linked for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `UNION ALL` operator.
The SQL UNION ALL operator is used to combine the result sets of 2 or more SELECT statements. **It does not remove duplicate rows between the various**

**Each SELECT statement within the UNION ALL must have the same number of fields in the result sets with similar data types.** So that you need create same column's with `null as ""`

Or you can try use `UNION`

**`UNION` removes duplicate rows.
`UNION ALL` does not remove duplicate rows.**

```
select *
from(

    SELECT id, user_id, user_agent, referrer, browser, device_type, IP, null as "name",
        null as "properties"
        FROM first f
        
        
        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT id, user_id, null as "user_agent", null as "referrer", null as "browser",
        null as "device_type", null as "IP",   name, properties
        FROM second s) x
    Where user_id = 1
```

Comment: Pleas don't post code-only answers. I have up voted, but you need to add an explanation. What's it doing, and why. For example the op may try to 'improve' your answer and mistakenly use `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score -1):

use Left join and use the foreign key to query the two tables

Comment: LEFT JOIN gives the same result

Comment: you want your result to have only 1000 rows without any repetition?